# Sum of all primes less than 2 million

Tags: java, primes

I tried to find out the sum of all primes less than 2,000,000 but it is giving the wrong answer. How do I improve my code?
I am Getting 1179908154 as an answer but the Original answer is 142913828922.

```
public class main {
    static boolean isPrime(int n) {
        if (n%2==0) return false;

        for(int i=3;i*i<=n;i+=2) {
            if(n%i==0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args) {
        int sum=2;
        for (int j=3;j<2_000_000;j=j+2){
            if(isPrime(j))
                sum+=j;
        }
        System.out.println("SUM : "+sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Integer overflow maybe? Try using `long` for the sum. Also, this would be much more efficient using a prime-sieve approach.

Comment: you're going to want to get more specific with your questions. a) we have no idea what "wrong" answer its giving, and b) people don't generally want to just read random dumps of source code, guess what's wrong, and then rewrite it for someone they don't know. Tell us EXACTLY what's going wrong, what form that takes, AND give us ONLY the relevant piece of source code, not ALL of it.

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks for Helping.

Comment: This is Project Euler, problem 10.

Comment: @masukomi i am new to java if i could have told that whats wrong in this code then why would have i asked this question.

Comment: even when you don't know a language there are simple mechanisms to find the code that causes a dump. Comment out the bottom half, does it still blow up? must be in the top half. comment out the remaining bottom half... repeat until it stops blowing up. put in print statements along the way... use a debugger. They may be crude but they work even when you don't understand a language well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution will [Sieve](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/sieve-of-eratosthenes.html) which works in `O(n)` time complexity where we get all the prime numbers less than `n` and then we can just add them up.

Answer (score 2):

int only goes up to 2^32, so you have overflow. You have to use long which goes up to 2^64.

Also, it's simpler to just use a sieve on a list of values up to 2 million to find all the primes (more efficient algorithm). Then go through the sieve, and sum up all the primes found. You trade off memory for greater speed and simpler code.

Comment: Thanks For Help i changed the Variable sum from int to long.